# How to add Cocoa pod dependency to custom framework swift

Tags: swift

I am using GVRSDK library pod in my custom framework but if i add this some other project target its not getting import. I am using module map because the library was not getting import in custom framewotk

error: using bridging header with framework target is unsupported.
Compilation Error due to adding private header in umbrella header Include of non modular header inside framework module .
Next i added Module Map File it got imported in Framework swift file. If i
import it in some other swift target it throwing error module not found.

Comment: Please share some images and code that you have implemented.

Comment: I created custom framework and added cocoa pod can you give steps for the correct implementation and with carthage i able to implement

Answer (score 0):

You should speciafied in your Podfile for which target you wanna install your pods

```
target 'FrameworkName' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'GVRSDK'

end
```

After that you can add the framework to your app from Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks
[image]

Comment: I have specified this in my cusotm framework and its working fine in framework but if i use this some other target or project its not working

Comment: You should specify this in your target where you wanna add the custom framework. How you make the connection between your framework and the target now?

Comment: Ya this one i tried but its not working. What i am doing is i am adding custom framework .framework (this contains GVRSDK Pod library) into my target like in build phase -> Embed Frameworks

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you got any solution?

Comment: You can add custom framework from File > New > Target > Cocoa Touch Framework. After that in Podfile you should specify which pods you wanna use for this custom framework.

Comment: Hi, I want to create a pod for my custom framework. And inside the podspec file want to add dependency pods.